# Pasting a very long string in eclipse editor

Tags: java, eclipse, editor

I am trying to paste a very long string in eclipse like:

```
String str = "verrrrrrrrry long string that hass 9000 characters";

I want it to appear as
String str = "verrrrrrrrry long"+
             "string that hass "+
             "9000 characters";
```

I tried the option mentioned here : [Paste a multi-line Java String in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159678/paste-a-multi-line-java-string-in-eclipse) , but that gives me a bunch of new lines inserted in the string which I dont want.

What I am getting currently is a long string that just wraps over itself on the same line.

Any pointers ?

Comment: what do you mean by `wraps over itself on the same line`?

Comment: he means its 1 super long ling.  (I think)

Comment: @asgs what I mean is , the string passes the end of the editor on that line and start re-writing from the beginning , overwriting [garbling] the string's begining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the settings worked for me , though they might be correct and I might have some other issue with my workspace.

Anyways, I was able to work through my problem with this expression:

```
cat Data.txt  | grep -o -E '.{1,70}' | sed -r 's/(.*)/        "\1"+/'
```

P.S:
If anyone else confirms that one of the answers given by anyone in this post works, I will accept it on their behalf , since I think my answer is not a direct answer to my question.

Answer (score 3):

Go in your Eclipse preferences:

under Java--> editor --> save actions --> Check off the "Format Srouce code" and "All Lines"

That will wrap it for you, when you save it.

Comment: that did not help exactly. Is it the apropriate combinations of these :
editor=>typing=>wrap automatically
editor=>typing=>Escape text when pasting into a strin gliteral
Java--> editor --> save actions --> Check off the "Format Srouce code" and "All Lines"

Comment: I meant does all the 3 properties above affect each other , so to get it right I want the correct values for each of them .. The option you mentioned did not wrap it for me, so I was wondering if some other setting is blocking it from doing it.

Comment: For me the only ones that is checked is: "In String Literals" the "Escape..." is not checked.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a macro on Notepad++ for instance and prepare the string there. 
After that you just need to paste it to Eclipse.