# Paste a multiline string in NetBeans IDE

Tags: java, netbeans, multiline

Is there a way to paste a multiline string in the NetBeans IDE and have it automatically converted to a string literal (with " escaped to \"), similar to the [Eclipse option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159678/paste-a-multi-line-java-string-in-eclipse)?

This can be very helpful for example to insert SQL source code.

See also: [Paste a multi-line Java String in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159678/paste-a-multi-line-java-string-in-eclipse)

Comment: I have Netbeans 7.3 and it does it when you simply paste the text `CTRL+V`. It escapes quotes and inserts newlines `\n`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Netbeans have this function within.

Type: String myString = "

Then paste your code and it will be formatted =)

Comment: Do you the way back? I would like to copy an escaped string and get the "original", unescaped version.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin for this: [Java Text Copy Paste Module](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/2748/?show=true)

> Helps copy and paste text from and to Java source code by converting
>   the text back and fourth between Java source and the original text
>   format such as SQL, XML, or HTML. It ties into the system clipboard,
>   so all one has to do is copy text in their favorite SQL or XML editor
>   then use the "Java Text Copy Paste Module" specific actions to
>   transform the code. Code can also be highlighted in the Java editor
>   and copied using the "Java Text Copy Paste Module" specific actions to
>   transform it back into the original text format for pasting into their
>   favorite utility editor. Works great with SQL and XML editors.