# Use RegEx to replace lines in eclipse

Tags: java, regex, eclipse

I have a huge xml as follows which I have to assign to a single string. This xml is really huge to so I have to go every line and put " " and + before each line. How can I do that with eclipse's find/replace using regEx.

```
<Student>
  <name></name>
  <age></age>
  <class></class>
  <section></section>
 // More tags
</Student>
```

What I want :

```
public final String studentRequest = "<Student>"
            + " <name></name> "
            + " <age></age> "
            + " <class></class>"
            + " <section></section> "
            + " </Student>" ;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it is in the file then why not simply read content of that file to String? Why do you want to put it as string directly via editor?

Comment: match `.*`, replace by `"\0" +`

Comment: Alternatively, You can copy the contents of the xml and paste it inside the quotes in `public final String studentRequest = "";` The IDE will automatically formats it.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2159931/1393766, but this will also add line separators like `\n` `\r` at the end of each line so I am not sure if that is what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Highlight the lines with the text, and remember to put the Scope to "Selected Lines".

Then you search for `(.)$` and replace by `$1"\+` (or `$1\\n"\+` if you need linebreaks), and replace `^(.)` by `"$1`.

This will turn

```
hello
world
!
```

into

```
"hello"+
"world"+
"!"
```

Add a variable assignment at the first line and a semicolon at the end, and you are done. There might be issues if you text contains special characters, though so try to clean those up first.