# Simple/Direct/Heredoc way of constructing a HTML string in Java

Tags: java, html, string, heredoc, convenience-methods

In python I can construct a HTML string without worrying about escaping special characters like < or " by simply enclosing the string in triple quotes like:

```
html_string = """
<html>
<body>
<p>My text with "quotes" and whatnot!<p>
</body>
</html>
"""
```

Is there a similar way to do this in Java?

Comment: For future reference, those sorts of things are usually called [heredocs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heredoc)

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/121513/403455) shows how to paste multi-line escaped strings in Eclispe.

Comment: For the quotes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034186/in-java-is-there-a-way-to-write-a-string-literal-without-having-to-escape-quote , for the multiline: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/878573/java-multiline-string

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It can't be done in Java like in Python. However if you are using Eclipse go to Window->Preferences->Java->Editor->Typing The last check box is "Escape text when pasting into a String literal". Check that. Now when you paste when your cursor is between quotation marks it'll be escaped.

Comment: There is always a checkbox somewhere ;o)

Answer (score 2):

To echo benjismith's trick from a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3034206/935154), you can use an alternate character and replace them afterwards:

```
String myString = "using `backticks` instead of quotes".replace('`', '"');
```

I found it helpful when I was writing tests with JSON

```
String json = "{`kind`:`file`,`sid`:802,`rid`:5678 ,`attrs`:{`name`:`FILE-WG-2468`}}".replace('`', '"');
// vs
String json = "{\"kind\":\"file\",\"sid\":802,\"rid\":5678 ,\"attrs\":{\"name\":\"FILE-WG-2468\"}}";
```

Comment: lacking `heredocs` is presently *the* item I most detest on java but this is a nice hack to reduce the pain.  I will compose the correct string then use Intellij "replace within selection" to say `~` (used less frequently than '`')

Answer (score 1):

No, but some tools escape it for you when you paste it, like eclipse.

Comment: Nice, didn't know that! How would you do it in Eclipse? I'm running Eclipse Galileo and when I paste HTML code it is just being copied.

Comment: Window>Preferences>Java>Editor>Typing check Escape text when pastin a string literal

Answer (score 1):

For the purpose mentioned, [Java Server Pages](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/JSPIntro.html) do the trick even without the tripple `"""`'s :-)

Answer (score 1):

## Text blocks

Text Blocks feature arrived in Java 15. For details, see [*JEP 378: Text Blocks*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/378).

Enclose your material in a pair of triple QUOTATION MARK characters.

```java
String html = """
              <html>
                  <body>
                      <p>Hello, world</p>
                  </body>
              </html>
              """;
```

Your [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) has likely been updated to be savvy in assisting you with editing text blocks. For example, [IntelliJ offers support](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/supported-java-versions.html).

Answer (score 0):

In Java source code, double quote is a special character, used to declare string literals. You cannot have a double quote in a String literal without escaping it.

In general, I would try to avoid hard-coding strings like that in source code, particularly if I found myself doing it a lot - as you've noted, they're a pain to deal with as source and they might be quite likely to change, in which case you could do without recompiling. If you don't need to supply runtime parts to the text data, you could get away with something as simple as reading in the data from a properties file, or you could use a templating engine like [Apache Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.6.2/user-guide.html) to keep the character data separate and still substitute variables at runtime - several of the examples in the linked user guide do exactly that with HTML.

Comment: I totally agree, but for a quick test (to pin down a bug) I always like to have some quick-n-dirty tricks up my sleeve ;o)

Comment: Agree - all depends on context. Sounds like the Eclipse trick is ftw in this case!

Comment: Embedded `heredoc's` are a core part of my development process especially in testcases and configuration related logic.  I was (fortunately) away from java for 6 years but coming back is v  painful with this front and center.   The trick above about replacing double quotes with something else is probably the least painful hack at this point.