# Java String use quotes without escape character

Tags: java, string, double-quotes

I know that it is possible to write double quotes in Java strings by putting `\` symbol before them. But if double quotes are used a lot in a string, is there a way to mark the string once, so there won't be a need to write the `\` symbol before each? (just like in C#, it is possible to put the `@` symbol before the string)
Example:

```
String quotes = @"""""""""""""""""""";
```

instead of

```
String quotes = "\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"";
```

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806973/working-with-long-strings-heredocs-in-java-the-readable-approach

Comment: Note (Jan. 2018), raw string literals might be coming for Java (JDK 10 or more): see [In Java, is there a way to write a string literal without having to escape quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48481601/6309).

Comment: @VonC Lets hope. Slowly but surely java is making progress :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't. But if you are too lazy to escape each of the double quotes, there are some trick that can do that. For example:

```
String quotes = "....................".replace(".","\"");
System.out.println(quotes);
```

output:  `""""""""""""""""""""`

Comment: just be sure the string doesnt contain punctuation

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no such way to write a `String` **literal** with unescaped quotes.

You can write the text externally and load it at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to *escape* all subsequent double quotes in code (that I know of). But, I recommend against hard-coding `String` literals. Instead, I suggest you use a [`ResourceBundle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) (or even [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html)). One benefit being you don't have to escape `String`(s) you read in that way.