# Do I need multiple result sets to execute SQL statement with multiple parameters in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

In my JSP I use the following code to fetch data from the database:

```
select * from parks where parkArea = 'abc' AND parkType = 'abcd'
```

I can't write the statement to execute correctly in my JSP, this is what I've tried:

```
statement = con.prepareStatement("select * from parks ("WHERE parkArea like "abc"") + ("AND parkType = "abcd"")")
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Show us your full code so that we'd be able to tell.

Comment: maybe you need to escape the quotes in your sql

Comment: Could you post the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
con.prepareStatement
("select * from parks WHERE parkArea like \"abc%\" AND parkType = \"abcd\"");
```

OR

```
con.prepareStatement
("select * from parks WHERE parkArea like 'abc' AND parkType = 'abcd'");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from parks ("WHERE parkArea like "abc"") + ("AND parkType = "abcd"")"
```

should be

```
"select * from parks WHERE parkArea like 'abc%' AND parkType = 'abcd')"
```

Comment: In 'abcd')" -> is ) needed?

Answer (score 0):

One thing it could be is that you are not [escaping your quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277944/escape-double-quotes-in-java). Try writing your inner quotes as \". It is difficult to determine the exact cause without seeing the error you are getting.