# Java string array double quote error

Tags: java

When I'm writing out my string, it tells me the string literal is not properly closed, but it looks like it is..? and then if i take out the /|\ the error moves down 2 lines to the legs. I researched and i cant seem to know what the problem is...

```
public static void printMan(int badGuesses) {
    String[] man = new String[];
             man={"______",
                  "|    |",
                  "|    o",
                  "|    |",
                  "|   /|\", //it tells me that i need to insert missing quote
                  "|    |",
                  "|   / \"
                 };
    int counter = 0;
    while (counter < badGuesses) {
        System.out.println(man[counter]);
    }
```

Comment: The head should be a capital O

Answer (score 9):

### Looks like you got an escape character

`\` Is an [**escape character**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character), you need to escape it too in this scenario. Otherwise, you'd get an unterminated string. `\"` means the actual character `"` rather than the start or an end of a string.

If you want the actual character `\` you need to escape it too: `\\`

```
 String[] man = new String[]{
              "|    |",
              "|    o",
              "|    |",
              "|   /|\\",  \\<- note the extra \
              "|    |",
              "|   / \\"   \\<- note the extra \ here too
             };
```

### The official Java Tutorial

See the [section on escape sequences](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html) in the official java tutorial:

> A character preceded by a backslash (\) is an escape sequence and has special meaning to the compiler. The following table shows the Java escape sequences (me: table in link)

### The language specification

This is of course in line with the [language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/):

```
StringLiteral:
   "StringCharacters"

  StringCharacters:
   StringCharacter
   | StringCharacters StringCharacter

  StringCharacter:
   InputCharacter but not " or \
   | EscapeSequence

   
EscapeSequence:
    \ b    
    \ t   
    \ n   
    \ f   
    \ r    
    \ "   
    \ '  
    \ \  < -  **THIS IS THE ONE YOU HAD**
    OctalEscape   /* \u0000 to \u00ff: from octal value */
```

([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3034195/1348195))

### A broader view

Wikipedia has an [interesting article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) on escape characters too:

> In computing and telecommunication, an escape character is a character which invokes an alternative interpretation on subsequent characters in a character sequence. An escape character is a particular case of metacharacters. Generally, the judgement of whether something is an escape character or not depends on context.

Noting:

> C, C++, Java, and Ruby all allow exactly the same two backslash escape styles.

Here is [another related question here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277944/escape-double-quotes-in-java) about escaping strings.

Comment: Now that's a good opportunity to learn about *community wiki*. Why this answer is a one? :D

Comment: @MarounMaroun to avoid gaining rep that was percieved as undeserved by OP

Comment: @MarounMaroun It's a trivial question, as such I did not want rep for it. On the other hand it's something a lot of users know about so it got a lot of edits from a lot of different users fast - doing this allowed us to produce a fast high quality answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are using an excape character..  `\"` causes `"` to be considered, add `\\"`

```
man={"______",
          "|    |",
          "|    o",
          "|    |",
          "|   /|\\",  \\ and extra slash here
          "|    |",
          "|   / \\"   \\ and here
         };
```

Answer (score 2):

You also declare bad the array, if you use initializater must be in this way cause if not you have to provide size to the array.

```
String[] man = new String[]{"______",
             "|    |",
             "|    o",
             "|    |",
             "|   /|\\",
             "|    |",
             "|   / \\"
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

`\` is an escape character. You have to escape it again, so the last line should look like:

```
"|   / \\"
```

Answer (score 0):

public static void printMan(int badGuesses) {

```
String[] man = new String[];
         man={"______",
              "|    |",
              "|    o",
              "|    |",
              "|   /|\", //it tells me that i need to insert missing quote
              "|    |",
              "|   / \"
             };
int counter = 0;
while (counter < badGuesses) {
    System.out.println(man[counter]);
}
```

Suggestion: 1. Add one extra \ before each \ you used in code.

1. Its a good practice to initialize in the declaration when you are initializing the array anonymously. Like 
   String []man=new String[]{"**_**","|      |"};