# How can I add escape characters to a Java String?

Tags: java, string, escaping

If I had a string variable:

```
String example = "Hello, I'm here";
```

and I wanted to add an escape character in front of every `'` and `"` **within the variable** (i.e. *not* actually escape the characters), how would I do that?

Comment: You mean in an editor?

Comment: Just type the \ character?

Comment: Use StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJava from apache commons

Comment: I mean using the `example` variable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escape double quotes in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277944/escape-double-quotes-in-java)

Comment: `example.replace("'", "\\'");`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm not claiming elegance here, but i *think* it does what you want it to do (please correct me if I'm mistaken):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String example = "Hello, I'm\" here";
    example = example.replaceAll("'", "\\\\'");
    example = example.replaceAll("\"", "\\\\\"");
    System.out.println(example);
}
```

outputs

```
Hello, I\'m\" here
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. Sorry I didn't explain the problem clearly.

Comment: Glad to help...in the future, realize that when talking about escaping characters, most people DON'T want to see a backslash in their code.  What you asked for is quite unusual.  Be sure to be super precise if deviating from what is typically done with in a given programming subject (e.g. escape characters).

Answer (score 3):

Try [Apache Commons Text](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/) library-

```
    System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.escapeCsv("a\","));
    System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.escapeJson("a\","));
    System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.escapeEcmaScript("Hello, I'm \"here"));
```

Result:

```
"a"","
a\",
Hello, I\'m \"here
```

Answer (score 3):

For others who get here for a more general escaping solution, building on Apache Commons Text library you can build your own escaper. Have a look at [StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html) for examples:

```
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.commons.text.translate.CharSequenceTranslator;
import org.apache.commons.text.translate.LookupTranslator;

public final class CustomEscaper {  

    private static final CharSequenceTranslator CUSTOM_ESCAPER = 
        new LookupTranslator(
            Map.of(
                "+" , "\\+",
                "-" , "\\-",
                // ...
                "\\", "\\\\"
            )
    );
    
    private CustomEscaper() {
        // hide
    }

    public static final String escape(String input) {
        return CUSTOM_ESCAPER.translate(input);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is only one quote then easy but if it is double quote then use like this

`eachClientName = eachClientName.replaceAll("'","\\\'");`

`eachClientName =eachClientName.replaceAll("\"","\\\\\"");`