# Escaped Data covertion in to java string

Tags: java

I have data in this format `<b><i>testing </i> </b>` and I need to convert this string into an equivalent java string. Can anyone suggest the process? 
Thank you

Comment: Do you want to remove the special character ??

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18471500/how-can-i-add-escape-characters-to-a-java-string for escaping quotes

Comment: no when i enter any data in my application i will save in escape formant that is for < it will save as &ls like that

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 import static org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml;
// ...
String source = "<b><i>testing </i> </b>";
String escaped = escapeHtml(source);
```