# how to print " inside print() function in java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-server

I have the following line in my code :

```
int check1 = stmt3.executeUpdate("update ShopSystem.Grocery where g_id="+g_id+" set g_name="+g_name);
```

It is showing me the following error :

```
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL     server version for the right syntax to use near 'where g_id=5 set g_name=Chikoo' at line 1
```

I think its because what is actually being passed to the SQL Server is :
      "update ShopSystem.Grocery where g_id=5 set g_name=Chikoo;

g_name is actually a String type. How should I pass that as a string in java print statement? Or is there any other mistake in my syntax?

Comment: set and where should be reversed.

Comment: Does `'` work instead? Generally, though, what about escaping it? `\"` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277944/escape-double-quotes-in-java

Comment: just curious from the question title, where is the `print()` function in all this? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to supply the quotes around the text value in your query, like so:

```
"update ShopSystem.Grocery set g_name='"+g_name +"' where g_id="+g_id+";
```

However, I would firmly advise you to use parameterized queries/prepared statements instead of concatenation.

```
PreparedStatement stmtUpdate = null;

String strUpdate = "update ShopSystem.Grocery set g_name= ? where g_id = ?";

stmtUpdate = yourconnection.prepareStatement(strUpdate);
stmtUpdate.setString(1,g_name);
stmtUpdate.setInt(2,g_id);
stmtUpdate.executeUpdate();
```

Note that the above code does not include exception handling and disposing resources, but it should get you started.

Comment: your previous solution about adding '' single quotes dnt work... continued to give the same error but with prepared statement it worked.. thanks :)

Comment: That's another reason to trust prepared statements apart from security - you avoid the mess of having to include quotes etc. in the concatenated query.

Answer (score 1):

I think g_name is a varchar type so you should enlose it with in quotes ('') like this

```
int check1 = stmt3.executeUpdate("update ShopSystem.Grocery set g_name='"+g_name+"' where g_id="+g_id );
```

Answer (score 0):

As shree.pat18 says I would advise you to use parameterized queries/prepared statements:

Anyway, you can use either simple quotes as:

```
"simple quote here -> ' text ' <-"
```

or double quotes as:

```
"double quote here -> \" text \" <-"
```