# WebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading giving invalid url

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-websettings

I'm setting `WebView`'s content as;

```
String displayBodyText = "<a href="scheme:/user_abd/data?q=from%3A%22ammar%40mydomain.com%22#title=%40Ammar%20">Ammar</a>"
webView.loadData(displayBodyText , "text/html", "utf-8");
```

And set the `WebViewClient` as;

```
linkDetailWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                            Log.d("TAG", url);
                            return true;
                        }
                    });
```

When clicked on the link in data, I'm getting `scheme:/user_abd/data?q=from:` instead of `scheme:/user_abd/data?q=from%3A%22ammar%40mydomain.com%22#title=%40Ammar%20`.

I'n unable to get this behavior of `WebView`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code I checked it works for me

```
String displayBodyText = "<a href=\"scheme:/user_abd/data?q=from:&#34;ammar@mydomain.com&#34;#title=@Ammar\">Ammar</a>";
web_view.loadData(displayBodyText , "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Webview client

```
web_view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            String m_url = URLDecoder.decode(url);
            Log.e("TAG",m_url);

            return true;
        }
});
```

Comment: Not working. In this case the url returned is `scheme:/user_abd/data?q=from:/`. There seems some issue with `%22`.

Comment: Now it's returning scheme:/user_abd/data?q==from:\\

Comment: Worked for me too, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape your invalid characters from your string:

```
String displayBodyText = "<a href=\"scheme:/user_abd/data?q=from%3A%22ammar%40mydomain.com%22#title=%40Ammar%20\">Ammar</a>";
```

You can't have double quotes in a string without escaping them: [Escape double quotes in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277944/escape-double-quotes-in-java)

Comment: What are invalid characters in this string? Double quotes are already encoded with '%22'.

Comment: The invalid double quotes are on the href attribute: `href="..."`. Compare your string with mine, and you'll see.

Comment: Oh yes. But this is typo here. Actually my string is escaped.