# Parse quites in text

Tags: google-sheets-api

I have this Java code which I use to set in Google sheets text and link:

```
.setFormulaValue("=HYPERLINK(\"" + get.getUrl() + "\",\"" + get.getTitle() + "\")"))
```

In general it woking fine but if I have "" into the title I get parse error. Example values:

```
.setFormulaValue("=HYPERLINK(\"" + http://test.test + "\",\"" + some "title" + "\")"))
```

Is there some solution to this problem?

Comment: Which parsing error ? At compile time? At runtime ?

Comment: @davidxxx I get this error during runtime.

Comment: And which is the full error message ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escape double quotes in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277944/escape-double-quotes-in-java) - particularly [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6277994/1270789), `get.getTitle().replaceAll("\"","\\\"")` or similar.