# Eclipse - Change raw data of multiple lines to String

Tags: eclipse

How to align group of lines into String automatically in Eclipse?

For Example

```
String s = "{ "QUOTE_DETAILS": { 
                             "BRANCH_CODE": "0000",
                             "TRANSACTION_TYPE": "TTTT",
                             "EXPIRY_DATE": "10/11/2012"
                            }}
```

Above group of lines should be auto aligned as

```
String s = "{ \"QUOTE_DETAILS\": { "
                          +"\"BRANCH_CODE\": "0000\", \"TRANSACTION_TYPE\": \"TTTT\","
                          +"\"EXPIRY_DATE": \"10/11/2012\""
                          +"  }}";
```

Do we have any option to achieve this?

Above example is just a sample, 
In reality I has some 40 odd lines of data, which need to be converted into String in java.

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121199/surround-with-quotation-marks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to *Preferences --> Java --> Editor --> Typing --> In String literals*, and check if option *Escape text when pasting into a string literal* is enabled.

Comment: Thanks for your response.. but i don't see any change after checking that check box.

Comment: i) Are you using the Java editor? ii) Have you applied the changes? iii) Try using it by writing `String s = ""`, then pasting the data *between* the quotation marks, iv) Press *Ctrl+Shift+F* for autoformatting. I believe it should work.