# Preserve formatting in copy/paste of eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

There is some generated code that builds a map. The values placed in map are multiline strings.
Example:

```
theMap.put("SOMEKEY", "Line 1 of string.  
               Also line 2 of string.  
               Perhaps more");
```

When I try to copy/paste the code to eclipse I get red errors due to the format of the value in the map.
I googled and [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121199/surround-with-quotation-marks/121513#121513) and here that there is a configuration in Eclipse to preserve the formatting in String literals but it does not seem to work in this case.
Is there any other configuration option?

Comment: How is that code generated?

Comment: Replace the line breaks by `"\n"`with a text-editor of your choice ore in eclipse. If you do not post process it by hand use an editor with macro features and write a macro than detects only the line breaks you want to replace.

Comment: @MrSmith42:How do I declare the line breaks in the replace function of the text-editor in order to replace them with `\n`?

Comment: In the find filed: simply copy and paste a newline from the text and in the replace filed write \n (as two characters)

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to keep space, use the \n character like this:

```
theMap.put("SOMEKEY", "Line 1 of string.\nAlso line 2 of string.\nPerhaps more");
```

Or if you want it multiline :

```
theMap.put("SOMEKEY", "Line 1 of string."
               +"\nAlso line 2 of string."
               +"\nPerhaps more");
```

If you paste only the string value into empty string (`""`), to be able to do this you need to have the following setting enabled: window>preferences>java>editor>typing and check the last option (escape text when pasting into a string literals)

Comment: My problem is that I need to **paste the existing fragments**. Not how to modify them

Comment: I've edited my post with an option which can help you. You must paste a string literal into empty quote for it to run

Comment: What does not work ? if you have the code : theMap.put("SOMEKEY", ""); and you paste your string into the empty string, it should format as expected if the option is checked

Answer (score 0):

```
theMap.put("SOMEKEY", "Line 1 of string.\nAlso line 2 of string.\nPerhaps more");
```

To split into multiple lines:

```
theMap.put("SOMEKEY", "Line 1 of string.\nAlso line 2 of string.\n" +
        "Perhaps more");
```

If you want to read multiple lines from a file:

```
String s, fullString;
while ((s = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    fullString += s + "\n";
}
bufferedReader.close();
theMap.put("SOMEKEY", fullString);
```

Comment: You mean do this manually?My problem is that I need to **paste the existing fragments**. Not how to modify them

Comment: @Jim Why do you need to paste the existing fragments? I could think of another way: you could read from a file.