# New line in String[] java swing

Tags: java, string, swing, newline

```
n.add(new CheckBoxGroupIntendedMeal(new String[]{"Breakfast", "Early\n" +"Breakfast", "Lunch", "Afternoon" + '\n' + "Snack","Dinner","Evening\\r?\\nSnack"}));
```

I have here checkbox with names ,there are name with one word and there are names with two words i want to make the two word names into two lines like this

`Early
Breakfast`

this are the sources i found here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121199/surround-with-quotation-marks/121513#121513) and [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454908/split-java-string-by-new-line) 
any idea is appreciated

Comment: Try using `<html>Early<br>Breakfast</html>`

Comment: i also saw that one i am trying to avoid using html here because when i do getText the <html> is coming with it so when i compare text i will have problems.

Comment: Well, you have a choice.  You either get the display to work and change the way you a determining which checkbox is selected (like using the objects `name` property or even better, it's `actionCommand` property) or you don't have multiple lines..

Comment: so its the only way.i better look for another way to get the text then..thanks for clarification

Comment: You should probably not be comparing display text. Cannot you attach a stable key or id or value to the checkboxes?

Comment: It will be the simplest...

Comment: thank you for the idea i will follow what you are saying i tried `setActionCommand` maybe this solve my problem.also i have one observation when i used `<html>`, `setDisplayMnemonicsIndex` is not working..its is just my observation