# Using .split() for multiple characters in Java

Tags: java, string, split

I'm trying to split an input by `".,:;()[]"'\/!? "` chars and add the words to a list. I've tried `.split("\\W+?")` and `.split("\\W")`, but both of them are returning empty elements in the list.

Additionally, I've tried `.split("\\W+")`, which returns only words without any special characters that should go along with them (for instance, if one of the input words is "C#", it writes "C" in the list). Lastly, I've also tried to put all of the special chars above into the `.split()` method: `.split("\\.,:;\\(\\)\\[]\"'\\\\/!\\? ")`, but this isn't splitting the input at all. Could anyone advise please?

Comment: You need a character class `[]` and you need to escape special characters (which are different for a character class than for a regex in general), so: `split("[.,:;()\\[\\]\"'\\\\/!? ]+")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`split()` function accepts a regex.

This is not the regex you're looking for `.split("\\.,:;\\(\\)\\[]\"'\\\\/!\\? ")`

Try creating a character class like `[.,:;()\[\]'\\\/!\?\s"]` and add `+` to match one or more occurences.

I also suggest to change the character space  with the generic `\s` who takes all the space variations like `\t`.

If you're sure about the list of characters you have selected as splitters, this should be your correct split with the correct Java string literal as @Andreas suggested:

```
.split("[.,:;()\\[\\]'\\\\\\/!\\?\\s\"]+")
```

BTW: I've found a particularly useful eclipse editor option which [escapes the string when you're pasting them into the quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121199/surround-with-quotation-marks/121513#121513). Go to `Window/Preferences`, under `Java/Editor/Typing/`, check the box next to `Escape text when pasting into a string literal`

Comment: No need to escape `.`, `(`, `)`, and `?` inside a character class.

Comment: Why do you have `"` and `)` twice? And you should show how to do it as a Java string literal, since the escaping gets worse there.